# How to print part of words in string by input using array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string

The C program below print the third until last character of 80 words strings

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char a[] = "computer";
  char start = 3;
  char length = 7;

  printf("%.*s\n", length, a + start);

  return 0;
}
```

the output :

```
puter
```

how to write in c code for print "n" last character of string

ex:

- string : "this computer"
- n inputed by scanf ex: 5

it will print to console

"puter"

Comment: You mean _letters_ (or _characters_) rather than _words_, don't you? "this computer" only contains 2 words.

Comment: Is the string of which you want to print a substring a given, or is it variable? in which case, the length needs to be variable, too, of course...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
char start = 3;
char length = 7;
```

to

```
int start;
int length;
```

and do as follows; I used a pointer in this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char a[] = "this computer";
    int start;
    int length;
    char *ptr = a; // Initializing ptr with first element of string literal.

    length = strlen(a); // Calculating the length of string literal
    scanf("%d", &start);

    if(start > length)
        start = length;

    ptr += length - start; // Adding the desired last number of elements/characters to be printed to the address ptr points to. 

    printf("%s\n", ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
5
```

Output:

```
puter
```

Comment: i need to scan "n" to print last n of the string "this computer".ex: n =5 it will print only "puter"

Comment: @haccks: perhaps add a check, as I have done in my answer: `if (start > length) start = length;`? to avoid problems..

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem; Good point! I did't think about that. Thanks.

Comment: @haccks if i want to scan string "this computer" too.so ,it needs to input string "this computer" and interger "5" in console.and show in console "puter".what i have to do?

Comment: Then you have to declare an array `a` as `char a[50];` (I assumed it of 50 bytes) and then use `fgets` to input string (you can use `scanf("%s", a);` but better not to use this). You can also do as `char *a;` and then allocate memory for it as `a = malloc(size_you_want_to_allocat)`.

Comment: @Gustibimo: If you go for `malloc`, you'll have to `free` that memory, too, obviously... :)

Answer (score 2):

In case the string, of which you're trying to print a substring is not hard-coded, you'll need to determine its length, too:

```
char some_string[] = "this computer";
char *out_ptr = &some_string;
int length, offset;
length = strlen(some_string);
scanf("%d", &offset);
out_ptr += length - offset;
printf("%s", out_ptr);
```

This allows you to pour this into a neat little function:

```
void print_substr(char *str_ptr)
{
    int offset, len = strlen(str_ptr);
    scanf("%d", &offset);
    if (offset > len) offset = len;
    str_ptr += len - offset;
    printf("%s\n", str_ptr);
}
```

And it's dead-easy to use, as you can see here, [on this code-pad](http://codepad.org/0c7UtUmP)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
void print_substring(const char *string, unsigned int start, unsigned int length)
{
  const size_t len = strlen(string);

  if(start >= len)
    return;
  if(start + length > len)
    length = len - start;
  for(; length != 0; --length)
    putchar(string[start++]);
  putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char a[] = "computer";
  char start = 3;
  char length = 8;
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("%.*s\n", n,&a[length-n]);

  return 0;
}
```